# How to encrypt data using RSA Private Key in Python?

Tags: python

Note: I'm utilizing VisualStudio on Python2.7 to perform my cryptography operations.

**Q1:** The operation I want to do is for the program to check and decipher the privateKey formula, based upon the ciphertext recieved from the PublicKey.

**Q2:** In the documentation, it described needing an algorithm to calculate the plaintext code. However, the documentation didn't specify how that equation would be calculated based upon the modulus. I'm trying to figure out how to write a privateKeyCheck for my RSAFunction, so once it runs the publickey, it then verifies the ciphertext.

**RSA_Functions.py**

```
class RSA:
def isPrime(n):

    # Corner case
    if (n <= 1):
        return False

    # Check from 2 to n-1
    for i in range(2, n):
        if (n % i == 0):
            return False

    return True

def modulus(p, q):
    return p * q

def eulerTotient(p, q):
    return (p - 1) * (q - 1)

def findFactors(x):
    factorList = []
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            factorList.append(i)
    return factorList

def publicKeyCheck(plist, qlist, keylist):
    for i in keylist:
        if i in plist and i != 1:
            print('invalid public key')

        elif i in qlist and i != 1:
            print('invalid public key')
        else:
            print(' public key is valid')
            break
```

As you can see above, for the equations we created two prime numbers (p q) that would compare the factors of the eulertotient and the public key to ensure they had no common factors with the Eurlertotient, and created a PublicKeyCheck to see if it matches with the RSA.

```
from RSAFunctions import RSA

print('Welcome to the RSA Algorithm Simulator.')
print('First you will need to select two Prime numbers.')

#step one generate two prime numbers
p = int(input('\nEnter a prime number(p) : '))
q = int(input('Enter a prime number(q) : '))

print("\nChecking to see if inputs are valid: ")
print(RSA.isPrime(p))
print(RSA.isPrime(q))

print("\nNow printing the Modulus:")
print(RSA.modulus(p, q))

print("\nNow printing the eulerTotient:")
print(RSA.eulerTotient(p, q))

publicKey = int(
    input(
        "\nPlease Enter a small two digit number that has no 
common factors with the eulertotient: "
    ))

factorseuler = RSA.findFactors(RSA.eulerTotient(p, q))
factorsKey = RSA.findFactors(publicKey)

print('\nVeryifying public Key:')

RSA.publicKeyCheck(factorsKey)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm failing to understand the question. Are you asking what's the RSA encryption/decryption formula?

Comment: Yes--and I apologize as this is my first attempt at crytography using python. I'm trying to figure out how to write a privateKeyCheck for my RSAFunction, so once it runs the publickey, it then verifies the ciphertext.

Comment: You don't really want to implement RSA in Python.  You will want to download a package to do it.  And why are you using Python 2.7?  It has expired.

Comment: The formula is [pretty simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Encryption), `c = m^e mod N`, `m = c ^ d mod N`, however the usual pre-cautions: 1) RSA is not used for message encryption, only for signing or for symmetric key exchange, 2) Formula is not safe to use as is without proper padding (OAEP), 3) RSA signing in practice is more than just encrypting the message with a private key, 4) nobody implements encryption algorithms by hand except for learning purposes, because there are so many things that can go wrong.